# How to Increase the Page Size in a Report Viewer at Asp.net Project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reportviewer

I am using a Report Viewer Page in a Asp Project, As my query is big i have Somany columns to be included in the Report viewer. But i am in a position that i cant increase the Page size of the Report to be Correctly fix the Entire Columns in the Report. Can any one help me on this.

Thanks in Advance,
Regards 
Kalyan.

Comment: you could set the orientation of the report to landscape, that would give you more space

Comment: ya, i have tried the Landscape orientation too, but only some Space is added, but even though i have still some columns to add in the Report, Is there any other way to give the Custom size to the Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page size is stored in the .rdc/.rdcl file.  Problem is if you change the page size dynamically you need to reposition and resize all the page elements.  I posted a helper class that can adjust the page size on the [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/vsreportcontrols/thread/1d5d3620-bb97-418b-8e68-371cfa5b6d1b).